# Excel VBA - Formatting script for automation

Tags: vba, excel, automation

So here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Open file: Pc_Profile
2. Create new sheet: Sheet1
3. Copy desired cells from Pc_Profile to Sheet1 (see script below)
4. Copy entire Sheet1 to new excel file: db.xls
5. Rename sheet to content of cell A5
6. Create new sheet for next script run

Basically I'm trying to automate an extraction of a TON of excel files into a single organized file. Each script call should extract to its own sheet so there's no overwritten information.

Here is what I have working so far. It just copies the desired cells to a new sheet within the same file.

```
' Create Excel object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' Open the workbook
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("\\[directory]\Pc_Profile.xls")

' Set to True or False, whatever you like
objExcel.Visible = True


objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A5:D5").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A8:B8").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A13:B13").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A15:D17").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A24:E26").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A28:B30").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A43:B43").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A13").PasteSpecial

objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").Range("A45:B45").Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").PasteSpecial

' Activate Sheet2 so you can see it actually pasted the data
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
```

I would really appreciate the extra push. I'm automating this for a work project and have no experience with VB - I just learned that on the go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things that are good practice to get into before I get to your actual question:

1) Any macro that you expect to run a long time should have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before any actual work is done in the code, this tells Excel not to bother with changing what's displayed on the screen (big performance booster). Be sure to include an `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` near the end of your code

2) Similar to #1, you generally want to include `Application.Calculation = xlManual` to boost performance. If you have large ranges of cells that your macro needs accurate up-to-date values from, it may be easier to leave the calculation automatic, but that doesn't appear to be the case in this instance.

3) You don't need to create a new Excel instance (which is what your first line of code does). You're already in a perfectly good instance of Excel. This also saves you having to close the other instance at the end of the macro (or worse from forgetting to do so and having memory get hogged by Excel processes that aren't really in use)

As to your specific problem, it sounds like you have more workbooks that Pc_profile to copy from, and that you're wanting to create a new "db.xls" with each run of the macro. Based on those assumptions all you need to do is nest your code starting with `'Open the workbook` and `objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A14").PasteSpecial` inside a Do While loop. The thing I'm not sure about is how to control the loop. If the list of files is always the same, you should just include a list on a sheet in the workbook that holds the macro and just iterate through that.

The other thing you should do for ease of coding, and to make the loop more effective is declare and use a Worksheet variable and set if for each workbook to the appropriate sheet to pull data from. Ex.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

'The Dim is outside your loop, but this would be inside it
Set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets("whatever_the_sheet's_name_is")
```

This way you can replace each occurrence of `objWorkbook.Worksheets("Pc_Profile").` with `ws.`, easier to type, easier to read, easier to update, and less error prone.

Next, you don't actually have code for moving Sheet1 to a new workbook, or renaming it. To move it (as well as the other Sheet1's yet to be created), you should, before getting to the Do While loop, have the following

```
Dim target as Workbook
Set target = Application.Workbooks.Add
```

Then at almost the end of the loop, you need `objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Target.Sheets(1)`

Last, you need to include `objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` after you've moved Sheet1 out of the Pc_Profile and renamed it.